# Decode information from Sybase transaction log file

Tags: sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I am looking for a way to decode the information stored in a Sybase database transaction log file (all queries issued to the database).

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got the answer right here.

first you need to install SQL anywhere which i'll assume you do.

then:

`"SQL anywhere install folder\Bin32\dbtran.exe" logName.log logName.log.txt`

the end result would look like this:

```
--CONNECT-1045-0016035758-DBA-2011-11-04 01:50 
--BEGIN TRANSACTION-1045-0016035769
BEGIN TRANSACTION
go
--UPDATE-1045-0016036065
UPDATE DBA.FAULT
   SET COUNT=21407,
      LAST_OCCURRENCE='2011-11-04 01:50:07.078'
 WHERE FAULT_ID=735
go
--COMMIT-1045-0016036092
COMMIT WORK
...
```

Comment: Hello, in this: "--COMMIT-1045-0016036092", how I know the date and time for this COMMIT, it's "0016036092"? Please, I need this... :/